# Sentry receiving my log messages but not my exceptions

Tags: java, dropwizard, sentry

I am facing an odd problem while using Sentry in a Dropwizard project.

I configured it in two applications with similar frameworks.

In one, I am getting all the log messages tracked properly but not the exceptions, as it should be, I have no idea why.

What I noticed is different from the app that works is this:

```
java.lang.Exception: some error
        at testEndpoint(EventResource.kt:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
```

vs the app that works:

```
io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 22059c429b65153e
! java.lang.Exception: Test Hello Exception
! at myMethod(TestResource.kt:40)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

I noticed there is an LoggingExceptionMapper involved, it is activated automatically by Dropwizard, but in the other does not seem to be there.

I am using sentry 1.7.23 and Dropwizard 1.3.9

On my dependencies:

```
implementation("io.sentry:sentry:$sentryVersion")
implementation("io.sentry:sentry-logback:$sentryVersion")
implementation("org.dhatim:dropwizard-sentry:1.3.1-1")
```

I have this last dependency as a helper to dont have to create my factory and specify the values for the logging appender on my config.yml

https://github.com/dhatim/dropwizard-sentry

both projects have the init in this way:

```
Sentry.init("some-value...")
```

my config.yml

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: console
    - type: sentry
      threshold: ${SENTRY_THRESHOLD}
      dsn: ${SENTRY_DSN}
      environment: ${SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT}
      release: 1.0.0
```

Any idea of what could be wrong?

No dependency of logback was needed since it is included on Dropwizard's core library

Comment: Did you check that any dependency conflict are occurring ?

Comment: yes, I have no conflicts :| or at least I cannot find them

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the LoggingExceptionMapper is in on the dropwizard-jersey project

Try to add a dependency to : dropwizard-jersey

Answer (score 0):

If there is depenedncy conflict then you can check with 2 way.

1) Just use below command on cmd or console of your IDE.This will show you dependency tree and you can search from the tree which library is conflicting.

```
      mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

Reference link : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

2) This is the most effective way to find dependency conflict. Add below plugin in your pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <rules>
                <dependencyConvergence />
            </rules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Then build the project using ***enforcer:enforce*** goal and it will show you the exact dependency with version which is getting conflict. If you find any conflict library just exclude them.

After using above way, If you faced same issue please try with upgrading version with 1.3 or try after adding org.glassfish.jersey.media dependency.

Hope any of the way will work for you.

Comment: its actually not a conflict, might be a filter that is catching those exceptions but I cannot find it